# Aggregating query for analytics

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics, analytics, business-intelligence

I'm using MySQL and trying to figure out best approach to generate time series for scans.

In the database, Events/Promotions/Reservations have many guests and
Events/Promotions/Reservations/Guests have many scans.

What approaches, algorithms are there, so that for specified time series (15, 30 minute intervals, 1, 4 hours, 1 day, 1 week, 1 month) I can generate the aggregate of scans (min, max, sum, avg) for each time period?

I was thinking of introducing an analysis services/DW to bring the results away from 3NF, but at this point it would be premature.

Other then doing nested queries for each of the types to aggregate them at the end, I may try to utilize stored procedures, though I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: `GROUP BY` comes to mind.  But without sample data and desired results, your question is a bit vague.

Comment: The desired results are simple: datetime - aggregate value. As for sample data - I'll assemble the DB fiddle shortly.

Comment: It is vague because I'm not certain how to put it in technical terms. Essentially, I need an aggregate of scans in time series for events/promotions/reservations occurring on specific day, week or month.

Comment: As it is, your question is not likely to get a proper answer. Would you please edit your post to show sample data and expected output ? This will help others understand what you are after.